# Request.Files.Count is always 0 MVC .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Ok so Im trying to do file uploads on my webpage however I have run into the issue where `Request.Files.Count > 0` is always 0 and wont enter the if statement. I have tried multiple ways of doing this and looked at multiple answers amongst this similar issue(there were a lot) but none of the solutions worked.

**Controller**

```
public class TicketController : CommonController
{
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(TicketViewModel model)
        {
            
            if (ValidateModel(model))
            {

                if (Request.Files.Count > 0) /*This is always 0*/
                {
                   HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
                }
            }
         }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "TicketController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FileUpload, new { type="file", name = "FileUpload"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileUpload) 
    </div>

}
```

**Model**

```
public class TicketViewModel
{
     public HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload { get; set; }
}
```

Tried adding or removing and changing the name in the View and the variable in the Model. But no luck always hits zero even when filled. My understanding is if a request key is detected it updates the variable to actually contain something. So there is a disconnect from my View and Controller and I can't figure it out. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
**Submit Button**

```
<div class="form-group bottom-button-row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-offset-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12 btn-panel">
            <div class="float-left">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:submit,disable:submitting" />
                <a role="button" class="btn btn-default" href="@ViewBag.CancelUrl" data-bind="attr:{disabled:submitting}">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            <div class="loader" data-bind="visible: submitting" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked file in your model Fileupload property ?

Comment: @dotnetstep That wont contain anything because `Request.Files` is empty and thats what fills that variable. And it doesn't even reach that point to begin with because it doesn't get past the `Request.Files.Count` check.

Comment: @dotnetstep Sorry I think I misinterpreted your original question. I checked the variable FileUpload in the model as well once we reached `isValid` it was still NULL. So its not filling at all sadly however other variables are in the model just fine such as email description etc etc. So its just file upload thats not working.

Comment: The way you are trying is  bit of problem. your form has button but its type is "button" instead change it to type ="submit" . When you try to post data with json then this approach will not work and you have to look for some other plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out another CSHTML file was calling this CSHTML file within a form already so I was nesting a form within a form which isn't supported I updated the outer form and all is well and it works. Comment your code people!